# Rename the rows of a column based on the corresponding rows of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
GRUPPO FORMATO | Creative Size 
_______________________________
'Lightbox'       | '200x100'
'Lightbox'       | '100x200'
'Something'      | 'hello'
```

If the rows of GRUPPO FORMATO are equal to 'Lightbox', I want to relabel the rows of 'Creative Size' with the following schema: the string 'Lightbox' and the corresponding string in the column Creative Size.
The desired output is:

```
GRUPPO FORMATO | Creative Size 
_______________________________
'Lightbox'       | 'Lightbox 200x100'
'Lightbox'       | 'Lightbox 100x200'
'Something'      | 'hello'
```

I've tried this but doesn't work:

```
db_new.loc[db_new['GRUPPO FORMATO']=='Lightbox', 'Creative Size']= str('Lightbox '+ db_new['Creative Size])
```

Any help?

Comment: try without the `str()`, just `... = 'Lightbox '+ db_new['Creative Size']`?

Comment: `db_new.loc[db_new['GRUPPO FORMATO'] == 'Lightbox','Creative Size'] = db_new['GRUPPO FORMATO'].str.cat(df['Creative Size'],' ')` very close, ditch the `str` and you are golden

Comment: @Ben.T already tried it doesn't work

Comment: @Manakin yep it works thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [np.where](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Creative Size'] = np.where(df['GRUPPO FORMATO'] == 'Lightbox', 
                               df['GRUPPO FORMATO'] + ' ' + df['Creative Size'], 
                               df['Creative Size'])
print(df)

  GRUPPO FORMATO     Creative Size
0       Lightbox  Lightbox 200x100
1       Lightbox  Lightbox 100x200
2      Something             hello
```